# Is there a simple way to add a wider div to a Y-scrolling container of other divs?

Tags: css

In this example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPGKPq

Is there a CSS way, using no Javascript, to have the full width of the blue div shown? I.e., rather than a horizontal scrollbar, show just the vertical scrollbar but the blue div extending to the left or right of the area?

I can absolute position the blue div over the container, but then it doesn't scroll with the container.

I think I have a way to dummy this up with a parent container the full width and a transparent background, but I feel like I'm missing something stupid.

Any ideas?

Backup of codepen sample:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="normal_div">
    test1
  </div>
  <div id="extension_div">
    Wide test
  </div>
  <div class="normal_div">
    test2
  </div>
  <div class="normal_div">
    test3
  </div>
</div>

#extension_div
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
}
#container
{
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
.normal_div
{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` on `#container` should get those divs sitting beside eachother. You could also set container to a super wide width and just have the body scroll horizontally.

Comment: @ShanRobertson, he wants NO horizontal scrolling available . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of your container div so that the blue div can occupy space without needing scroll bars. Then define a width for `.normal_div`

```
#extension_div
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
}
#container
{
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
.normal_div
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```